# Separar grupos de elementos de un array y formar un nuevo array javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Hola estoy intentando hacer que los elementos de un array que son 21 se separen en grupos de a tres y que esos grupos formen un array nuevo cada uno pero no sé como hacerlo, se me ocurrió hacer un bucle for para tomar los primeros tres elementos del array y meterlos en otro mediante push() luego eliminar esos tres elementos del array antiguo y el bucle se aplicaría de igual forma con los demás, pero esto no me resultó

```js
let notas = ['C', 'c#', 'D', 'd#', 'E', 'F', 'f#', 'G', 'g#', 'A', 'a#', 'B'];
let notausuario = "";
let formula = [0,2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1];
let triadas=[0,2,2];
let f=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
let almacen=[];
let almacentriadas=[];

function capturarnota() {
  let notausuario = document.getElementById("nota").value;
  let posicion = notas.indexOf(notausuario);
  for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {

    posicion += formula[i]

    if (posicion >= notas.length) {
      posicion = posicion - notas.length
    }

    let posicion1 = notas[posicion];
    almacen.push(posicion1);
  }
  console.log(almacen);
  creartriadas();
};
function creartriadas() {
  let contador=0;
  let array=[];
  for (var i = 0; i < almacen.length; i++) {
      let x=f[i];
  array.push(x+=triadas[0],x+=triadas[1],x+=triadas[2]);
  }
  console.log(array);
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i]>=almacen.length) {
      array[i]=array[i]-almacen.length;
    }
    almacentriadas.push(almacen[array[i]]);
  }
console.log(almacentriadas);
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="programa.js"></script>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form class="" action="index.html" method="post">
      <input type="text" id="nota">
    </form>
    <input type="button" onclick="capturarnota();">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No queda muy claro lo que quieres hacer. Por favor edita la pregunta para agregar ejemplos del contenido original y cómo debe quedar al final.

Comment: `de un array que son 21` yo no veo ningún array con 21 elementos. Por favor aclara lo que quieres hacer porque no se entiende

Comment: Inicia desde el 0 hasta el 20 osea que son 21 si se cuenta desde el 1, lo que necesito es que coja los 3 primeros osea el 0,1,2 y los meta a un array, luego los otros tres osea sería 3,4,5 en otro array luego los otros tres y así hasta terminar osea que quedarían 7 arrays de 3 elementos cada uno.

Comment: Hola @Liz, ¿buscas almacenar en 7 grupos de array 3 elelementos del array que tiene los 21 elemento (valga la redundancia)? Y lo otro, qué papel cumple la caja de texto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Había varias cosas por corregir, por ejemplo:

- No siempre realizas validaciones al calcular posiciones de notas
- No estabas agrupando la salida en triadas (arreglos de 3 elementos)
- Tenías un ciclo extra, que podía omitirse para simplificar y dejar el código más legible

Todavía me quedaron algunas dudas, por ejemplo:

- `f` tiene la misma longitud que `almacen`
- Dentro del ciclo tienes `let x=f[i];` y, como los valores de `f` son consecutivos, `x` es igual a `i`, a menos que sea parte de otra fórmula y planees cambiarlo posteriormente

Me tomé la libertad de cambiar el *input* por *select* y llenarlo con cada nota, para que el valor siempre sea adecuado.

Revisa comentarios en el código para saber los cambios:

```js
let notas = ['C', 'c#', 'D', 'd#', 'E', 'F', 'f#', 'G', 'g#', 'A', 'a#', 'B'];
let notausuario = "";
let formula = [0,2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1];
let triadas=[0,2,2];
let f=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
let almacen=[];
let almacentriadas=[];

// Llenar select cuando se cargue la página
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    // Me gusta más querySelector que getElementById
    let sel = document.querySelector('#nota');
    // Recorrer notas para llenar select
    notas.forEach(nota => {
        // Crear opción, asignar valor y texto
        let opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.value = nota;
        opt.text = nota;
        // Agregar opción a select
        sel.appendChild(opt);
    });
});

// Validar que la posición corresponda a una nota
function validaPosicion(pos) {
    return (pos <= notas.length) ? pos : pos - notas.length;
}

function capturarnota() {
  let notausuario = document.querySelector('#nota').value;
  let posicion = notas.indexOf(notausuario);
  for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    posicion = validaPosicion(posicion + formula[i]);
    // Guarda la posición en lugar de nota
    almacen.push(posicion);
  }
  console.log(almacen);
  almacentriadas = creartriadas();
  console.log(almacentriadas);
};
function creartriadas() {
  let contador=0;
  let array=[];
  // Se puede hacer en un solo ciclo
  for (var i = 0; i < almacen.length; i++) {
      let x=f[i];
      // Se guardan posiciones, porque aquí se hacen más cálculos
      // Directamente se crea cada triada [nota1, nota2, nota3]
      array.push([
          notas[validaPosicion(x+=triadas[0])], // Hay que validar posición
          notas[validaPosicion(x+=triadas[1])],
          notas[validaPosicion(x+=triadas[2])]
      ]);
  }
  // Devolver triadas
  return array;
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="programa.js"></script>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form class="" action="index.html" method="post">
      <select id="nota"></select>
    </form>
    <input type="button" onclick="capturarnota();">
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const miArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
let result = [];
let current = [];

miArray.forEach(el => {
  if (current.length == 3) {
    result.push(current);
    result.push(el);
    current = [];
  } else {
    current.push(el); 
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

Puedes hacer un `forEach`, definiremos `current` para obtener los 3 índices del array

Puedes recorrer el resultado de la siguiente manera

```js
const miArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
let result = [];
let current = [];

miArray.forEach(el => {
  if (current.length == 3) {
    result.push(current);
    result.push(el);
    current = [];
  } else {
    current.push(el); 
  }
});

result.forEach(el => {
  if (typeof el == "object") {
    console.log(el[0],el[1],el[2], result[result.indexOf(el)+1]);
  }
});
```

Como tenemos el elemento y no el índice, usaremos `indexOf` para obtener el índice

Además, puedes usar un array de 4 elementos, si es que no hay problema.

```js
const miArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
let result = [];
let current = [];

miArray.forEach(el => {
  if (current.length == 3) {
    current.push(el);
    result.push(current);
    current = [];
  } else {
    current.push(el); 
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo resolví, gracias por tomar su tiempo para explicar Triby y anythingg pero lo que necesitaba era simplemente encapsular 3 numeros en un array y luego otros tres en otro. Tal vez no me expliqué bien, Triby lo que necesitaba que se encapsulara eran los elementos que estaban en almacentriadas. Aquí la solución un poco rara pero estoy aprendiendo jaja. Luego le cambiaré a select me pareció que es más comodo, gracias.

```js
let notas = ['C', 'c#', 'D', 'd#', 'E', 'F', 'f#', 'G', 'g#', 'A', 'a#', 'B'];
let notausuario = "";
let formula = [0,2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1];
let triadas=[0,2,2];
let f=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
let almacen=[];
let almacentriadas=[];

function capturarnota() {
  let notausuario = document.getElementById("nota").value;
  let posicion = notas.indexOf(notausuario);
  for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {

    posicion += formula[i]

    if (posicion >= notas.length) {
      posicion = posicion - notas.length
    }

    let posicion1 = notas[posicion];
    almacen.push(posicion1);
  }
  console.log(almacen);
  creartriadas();
};
function creartriadas() {
  let contador=0;
  let array=[];
  for (var i = 0; i < almacen.length; i++) {
      let x=f[i];
  array.push(x+=triadas[0],x+=triadas[1],x+=triadas[2]);
  }
  console.log(array);
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i]>=almacen.length) {
      array[i]=array[i]-almacen.length;
    }
    almacentriadas.push(almacen[array[i]]);
  }
  console.log(almacentriadas);
  agrupar();
};
function agrupar(){
  let tritri=[];
  for (var i = 0; i < f.length; i++) {
    tritri.push([
          almacentriadas[0], // Hay que validar posición
          almacentriadas[1],
          almacentriadas[2]
      ]);
      almacentriadas.splice(0, 3);
  }
  console.log(tritri);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="programa.js"></script>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form class="" action="index.html" method="post">
      <input type="text" id="nota">
    </form>
    <input type="button" onclick="capturarnota();">
  </body>
</html>
```